# Copying/pasting/duplicating java files in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies, copy-paste, code-duplication

My background with eclipse is limited to introductory java college courses. This is my first time working on a project with over one million lines of codes and so many folders. Here's what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to copy/paste java classes from one directory to another. Some of these classes have many imports and it makes duplicating very tedious. Currently, I copy/paste each dependency and change their package names. Then, I would have to copy/paste their dependencies as well, and so on. Each class I copy exponentially adds more classes to copy.

Is there an more automated way or at the least dependency viewer to keep track of where all the imports are coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use option `Refactor > Move` on while right-clicking the project name.

Here is more information on it:
[Refactor > Move - Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-10.htm)

It will change the packages names automatically. Don't ever do it manually.

Comment: Appreciate the tip and the resource. I'll look through the eclipse documentation. From your suggestion, this only moves a file to a new location. Is there possible a some sort of "refactor copy" option? I'm trying to copy java classes to multiple new directories and I also have to copy whatever dependencies they have as well. Then, I have to refactor the import and package paths of each classes.

Comment: Make a copy of class. Refactor > move. Refactor name. You will have your work done. If this answer satisfies you please accept it.

Comment: If we can copy a file structure in explorer and paste it into an Eclipse project. Why on earth should eclipse not support copying a file structure from one project to another. That's just plain annoying.